# Is there any equivalent in VS for "Type Hierarchy View" as with eclipse?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, ide, refactoring

I want to see which classes are implement from a particular Interface. I know this is possible with the Eclipse by saying "Type Hierarchy View". Is is possible in VS 2008?

I guess that it may be possible with Resharper. But without it, is it possible? Any workarounds?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [Reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/reflector/) on your assembly. Simply locate your interface in the browser and expand the "Derived Types" subnode.

If you want to stay inside Visual Studio you can still right click the interface type (either in the text editor or in "Class View"). From the context menu select "Find All References". This search will also include places where the interface is used, e.g. as a method parameter.

Answer (score 1):

Finally, an extension ([Type Hierarchy Viewer](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=munyabe.TypeHierarchyViewer&ssr=false#overview)) is launched which works with VS2015, VS2017 and VS2019.